# Manipulate external XML files after they have been loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I have loaded several external SVG files using `d3.xml()` and the [queue.js](https://github.com/mbostock/queue) library. I can manipulate each file as it is loaded (changing its position and its color) using the following code ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xzc0Lgf/7/)):

```js
var width = 300, height = 300;
var sampleSVG = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr( {width: width, height: height} );

var shapes = [
  { url: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2467665/shapes-24.svg", color: 'purple' },
  { url: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2467665/shapes-23.svg", color: 'red' }
];

var q = queue();
shapes.forEach(function(shape) { 
  q.defer(d3.xml, shape.url, "image/svg+xml"); 
});

q.awaitAll(function(error, results) { 
  sampleSVG.selectAll('g.shape').data(shapes)
    .enter().append('g').attr('class', 'shape')  
    .attr('transform', function() {
      return 'translate(' + Math.random()*(width-50) + ',' + Math.random()*(height-50) + ')'
    })
    .each(function(d,i) {
      this.appendChild(results[i].documentElement);
      d3.select(this).select('svg').select("*")
        .attr("transform", "scale(0.2)")
        .attr("stroke", function() { return d.color; });
    })
});
```

I want to access the shapes just like normal d3 objects after they all load. For example, after reading them in as shown above, I want to execute a simple transition to make them all black:

```
sampleSVG.select(".shape svg *").transition().delay(1000).attr("stroke", "black");
```

But this doesn't work.

How can I read in these external SVG files so that I can manipulate like normal?

Comment: You're trying to update the colours outside of the q.awaitAll function.  That means that the sampleSVG.select(...) line will be run before the shapes exist in the DOM.  Try moving it inside the q.awaitAll function, like in http://jsfiddle.net/hk367c5q/ and you should be OK.

Comment: @BenLyall Yeah, that works, but the problem is I have a lot of other dynamic things going on that don't involve these shapes. I'd like to have everything load "under the hood" and then start the dynamic chain as if these were normal d3-produced shapes.

Comment: Sure... that makes perfect sense, you just have to delay calling the sampleSVG.select(...) line until after you have finished manipulating the DOM.  As it stands, you're calling it too early, before the SVG elements have come into existence.

Comment: Is there a way to determine when I've finished manipulating the DOM so that I can start the sampleSVG.select(...) line etc only when that returns true?

Comment: That's going to depend quite a bit on your setup.  If it's a simple thing like in your jsfiddle, just wrap the sampleSVG.select(...) line in a function and call that function from the end of your q.awaitAll.  If you've got a complex set of functions all manipulating the DOM, then you're going to need some way of tracking when everything is complete.  Hint: the queue library you're already using could definitely help you with this.

Comment: Great, I think I got it from here. If you want to turn your comments (esp 1st and 2nd) into an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to update the colours of your SVG shapes before they have been created.  If you move the

`sampleSVG.select(".shape svg *").transition().delay(1000).attr("stroke", "black");`

inside the `q.awaitAll(...)` function, then it'll run after the shapes have been created in the DOM, and the select will work.

Any method that delays the calling of

`sampleSVG.select(".shape svg *").transition().delay(1000).attr("stroke", "black");`

until after your DOM manipulations are complete will work.  You could wrap it in a function call, and call that function at the end of the `q.awaitAll(...)` or you could make additional use of the `queue` library, in a similar fashion to your current use of it.